# When you were young, you didn't fear me

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> When you were young, you didn't fear me
>
> But when you became older you found me, and you really had a scare
>
> Black or white you didn't care, as long as I wasn't there
>
> If you try to be rid of me I'll serve you a scar
>
> It'll make perfect even more far
>
> And I dare you to, smoke a cigar
>
> If you do, we might both get worse
>
> And I might stick around, a hole to be your curse

**What am I?**

> Don't judge the rhyme scheme!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be

> **A pimple** (or acne).

```
When you were young, you didn't fear me
```

> Young people don't get pimples.

```
But when you became older you found me, and you really had a scare
```

> Adolescents start getting them, and hate them, often afraid they'll be made fun of for their appearance and/or that they'll seemingly never go away.

```
Black or white you didn't care, as long as I wasn't there
```

> Blackheads or whiteheads.

```
If you try to be rid of me I'll serve you a scar
```

> Trying to pop pimples can leave scarring

```
It'll make perfect even more far
```

> Scarring, or acne, makes perfection even farther away. Either fits. I think scarring was intended?
>  (Thanks @Daedric for helping me parse this line)

```
And I dare you to, smoke a cigar
```

> Smoking has been linked to acne.

```
If you do, we might both get worse
```

> Smoking can make acne worse, and lead to scarring on its own. It can also harm your health.

```
And I might stick around, a hole to be your curse
```

> The hole-like scar left behind.

Comment: a scar on your face makes you less "perfect", further from perfect

Comment: You are correct (: And thanks for the feed back I'll edit it my question.

Comment: Thanks, adjusted my answer to match your edits. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are:

> Cancer

When you were young, you didn't fear me

> Children may not understand or be aware of cancer

But when you became older you found me, and you really had a scare
Black or white you didn't care, as long as I wasn't there

> Found and/or were diagnosed

If you try to be rid of me I'll serve you a scar
It'll make perfect, even more far

> Have a tumour surgically removed

And I dare you to, “smoke a cigar”
If you do, we might both get worse
And I might stick around, to be your curse

> Referring to lung cancer

Comment: Hmm, not quite it doesn't fit every line really well.  I added a little to the last time to help lead a bit better.